# Summation in euler's terms

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

The sum $$\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)^2r^2(n-2r)$$ is either equal to $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{-2k\pi i}{n}} or \sum_{k=0}^{n}e^{\frac{2k\pi i}{n}}$$Which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Substituting $r\mapsto n-r$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)^2r^2(n-2r)
&=\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)^2r^2(2r-n)\\
&=-\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)^2r^2(n-2r)
\end{align}
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{\frac{-2k\pi i}{n}}=\frac{e^{\frac{-2n\pi i}n}-1}{e^{\frac{-2\pi i}n}-1}\\
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:
$$(n-r)^2r^2(n-2r)=(n^2-nr)^2(n-2r)=n^5-4n^4r+5n^3r^2-2n^2r^3$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^n(n-r)^2r^2(n-2r)=n^5\sum_{r=0}^n1-4n^4\sum_{r=0}^nr+5n^3\sum_{r=0}^nr^2-2n^2\sum_{r=0}^nr^3$$